# Cannot update hosted service Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I was trying to update one of my hosted service in Windows Azure and the update crashed.  When I tried to do any operation now, stop, delete or update the hosted service I always get this error :

Windows Azure is currently performing an operation with x-ms-requestid

Someone got that one time ?

Thanks

Comment: I am getting this all the time now, Its a real pain.  symptoms include: No Stop option for the cloud service, You cannot delete the cloud service.  If you send a stop command to the cloud service then you get an error saying 'Windows Azure is currently performing an operation with x-ms-requestid'    There seems to be no way to fix this other then waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Management API (AMAPI) can be temperamental.  There’s not much you can do about this one other than let the operation internally timeout.  I have seen hosted service deployments be stuck in a transitioning state for extended periods of time (4-8 hours) although this is uncommon.

You should open a support incident with Microsoft.  Even if it resolves itself faster than they get to you, it is good to let them know that this is happening.